Fastest way to find which hours have 0 rows in a table with a month's data?
I have a Very Large/slow table (35gb data, 70gb indexes) on an Azure SQL MI that's roughly this:
create table a (id int identity, mydate datetime, fielda varchar(10), fieldb money, fieldc char(50), fieldd datetime)
create index ncidx__a__mydate on a (mydate)

I want to get a list of which hours have 0 rows, though which hours have any rows is close enough (bang it against a numbers table and you can get a list). I was trying to think of the bare minimum needed.
I could do something like this, but would need 30*24 of them for each month. Seems like something a function with a cross-apply could do.
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '20240703 1am test' res) a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable WHERE mydate >='20240701 01:00:00' AND mydate <'20240701 02:00:00')

I came up with this (based off an Itzik Ben-Gan query), which... works, and is good enough for me for now. (3 minutes for a month, 200m rows, 34gb data, 70gb of indexes including the one you see. It does 715992 logical reads).
SELECT orderday, orderhour, MIN(mydate) AS mindate
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(day(mydate), datepart(HOUR,mydate)))
               AS D(orderday, orderhour)
WHERE mydate >='20240501' AND mydate <'20240601'
GROUP BY orderday, orderhour

But is there a faster way? I don't need a min date, I just need to know if there are ANY rows in there. It seems like it could be almost instant, but the logic of doing that is beyond me. Thanks.

An index on a single column is unlikely to be helpful, it's not covering. I wouldn't be surprised if the data engine decides to scan rather than do a seek followed by many key lookups.

I hope you mean 35 TB of data, because 35 GB shouldn't take a lot of time to just aggregate

Performance related questions need 1) Table definitions, 2) Index definitions & 3) The execution plan using "Paste The Plan"

What SQL Server version are you running? SQL Server 2022 has several useful functions like GENERATE_SERIES() and DATETRUNC() that may be useful in the solution.

@ThomA it's a simpler version. The real index has a couple more and is used for some very specific things, but I wanted it simple for this.

@siggemannen yeah, that's what I expected, "the cloud" and all that. But even with a fairly tight index (only 7gb) it still was taking over 10 minutes to come back with a groupby... which is why I went down the rabbit hole of exists and min and the like. And now that I have this, I'll be using it for some other things. What was a "huh, I wonder if" is probably going to get massively reused over the years. Cheers! :)

You are on the right track with the mydate index. Most solutions would likely involve either a loop join and an index seek (probe) into that index, or a range scan of the relevant portion of the index (better than a table scan) that is fed to logic that looks for gaps.
The most obvious and possibly the most efficient solution would be to generate a range of data/time values that is then filtered by a where not exists(...) clause. Something like:
declare @FromDate datetime = '2024-07-01'
declare @ToDate datetime = dateadd(month, 1, @FromDate) -- Exclusive
declare @DiffHours int = datediff(hour, @FromDate, @ToDate)

-- Using not exists
-- Loop join and index seek (probe)
select h.Hour
from generate_series(0, @DiffHours - 1) s
cross apply (select dateadd(hour, s.value, @FromDate) as Hour) h
where not exists (
    select *
    from a
    where a.mydate >= h.Hour
    and a.mydate < dateadd(hour, 1, h.Hour)
)
order by h.Hour

For a one month range, the index would be probed by the exists clause about 750 times.
Another approach would be to scan the date range, reduce it to a set of distinct hours values and then subtract those values from a generated list of all hours. The subtract operation could be performed using except or with a left join ... where right-side is null construct.
declare @FromDate datetime = '2024-07-01'
declare @ToDate datetime = dateadd(month, 1, @FromDate) -- Exclusive
declare @DiffHours int = datediff(hour, @FromDate, @ToDate)

-- Using except
-- Index seek (range scan) and merge join (or spool + loop join)
select h.Hour
from generate_series(0, @DiffHours - 1) s
cross apply (select dateadd(hour, s.value, @FromDate) as Hour) h
except
select distinct datetrunc(hour, a.mydate) as Hour
from a
where a.mydate >= @FromDate
and a.mydate < @ToDate
order by Hour

-- Using left join
-- Index seek (range scan) and merge join (or spool + loop join)
-- (Slighly different from the "except" plan)
select h.Hour
from generate_series(0, @DiffHours - 1) s
cross apply (select dateadd(hour, s.value, @FromDate) as Hour) h
left join (
    select distinct datetrunc(hour, a.mydate) as Hour
    from a
    where a.mydate >= @FromDate
    and a.mydate < @ToDate
) h2
    on h2.Hour = h.Hour
where h2.Hour is null
order by H.Hour

Finally, an ordered scan of the date range can be performed, checking for gaps using the LAG() window function to compare the current value to the prior.  A UNION ALL is included to ensure that we have the end-cases (first and last hour) covered.
There might be a slight performance gain if the UNION operations are factoring out to then next outer query level, since data is already sorted, but the cost is two more index seeks. Both versions follow.
declare @FromDate datetime = '2024-07-01'
declare @ToDate datetime = dateadd(month, 1, @FromDate) -- Exclusive

-- Index seek (range scan), using lag() to check for gaps.
-- A union-all is used to ensure we have the end-cases covered.
select
    dd.MissingHours,
    dateadd(hour, 1, dp.PriorHour) as FromHour,
    dateadd(hour, -1, Hour) as ThruHour
from (
    select
        d.Hour,
        lag(d.Hour) over(order by d.Hour) as PriorHour 
    from (
        select dateadd(hour, -1, @FromDate) as Hour
        union all 
        select @ToDate as Hour
        union all 
        select datetrunc(hour, a.mydate) as Hour
        from a
        where a.mydate >= @FromDate
        and a.mydate < @ToDate
    ) d
) dp
cross apply (select datediff(hour, dp.PriorHour, dp.Hour) - 1 as MissingHours) dd
where dd.MissingHours >= 1
order by dp.PriorHour

-- Index seek (range scan), using lag() to check for gaps.
-- Factoring out this union /might/ yield a slight performance gain,
-- since data is already sorted, but the cist is two more index seeks.
select
    dd.MissingHours,
    dateadd(hour, 1, dp.PriorHour) as FromHour,
    dateadd(hour, -1, Hour) as ThruHour
from (
    select
        d.Hour,
        lag(d.Hour) over(order by d.Hour) as PriorHour 
    from (
        select datetrunc(hour, a.mydate) as Hour
        from a
        where a.mydate >= @FromDate
        and a.mydate < @ToDate
    ) d
    union all
    select
        datetrunc(hour, min(a.mydate)) as Hour,
        dateadd(hour, -1, @FromDate) as PriorHour
    from a
    where a.mydate >= @FromDate
    and a.mydate < @ToDate
    union all
    select
        @ToDate as Hour,
        datetrunc(hour, max(a.mydate)) as PriorHour
    from a
    where a.mydate >= @FromDate
    and a.mydate < @ToDate
) dp
cross apply (select datediff(hour, dp.PriorHour, dp.Hour) - 1 as MissingHours) dd
where dd.MissingHours >= 1
order by dp.PriorHour

The above yields ranges instead of individual rows for each missing hour. This might be desirable.  If not, the above can be modified with a GENERATE_SERIES() and DATEADD() to expand each resulting range.
select dateadd(hour, s.value, dp.PriorHour) as Hour
from (
    ...
) dp
cross apply (select datediff(hour, dp.PriorHour, dp.Hour) - 1 as MissingHours) dd
cross apply generate_series(1, dd.MissingHours) s
where dd.MissingHours >= 1
order by Hour

See this db<>fiddle for a demo of each of the above with execution plans using some generated test data having 1-, 3-, and 5-hour gaps.
You can run performance tests against your live data to see what works best for you.
Sample results (discrete hours and hour ranges):



Hour




2024-07-05 04:00


2024-07-11 10:00


2024-07-11 11:00


2024-07-11 12:00


2024-07-11 13:00


2024-07-22 21:00


2024-07-22 22:00


2024-07-22 23:00


2024-07-23 00:00


2024-07-23 01:00


2024-07-23 02:00






MissingHours
FromHour
ThruHour




1
2024-07-05 04:00
2024-07-05 04:00


3
2024-07-11 10:00
2024-07-11 12:00


5
2024-07-22 21:00
2024-07-23 01:00



OLDER SQL SERVER VERSIONS
The above SQL solutions use the DATE_TRUNC() and/or GENERATE_SERIES() functions available in SQL Server 2022 and later.
For earlier versions of SQL Server, the DATE_TRUNC(hour, xxx) function can be replaced with the calculation dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, xxx), 0). The GENERATE_SERIES() function can be replaced with a number generator wrapped up in a CTE or cross apply. There are many techniques out there, but for this application, you can use a variation of the following:
cross apply (
    select top (n) -- 1..n
        row_number() over(order by (select null)) as value
    from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n1(n) -- Up to 10
    cross join (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n2(n) -- Up to 100
    cross join (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n3(n) -- Up to 1000
) s

The row_number() function produces numbers starting at 1. Subtracting 1 and adjusting the top (n) value is needed for zero-based or other-based ranges. Add more cross joins if more than 1000 values are needed.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo that works for earlier SQL Server versions back to at least 2014.

Wow, that's a superb answer, dude! Thanks for putting a ton of detail in this response! I'm fortunately(?) on Azure SQL MI, so I get the new bells and whistles - but the performance on certain things is a head-scratcher (and no, it's not the new CE) .. UPDATE: WOW. 9k reads for a month, compared to 98k reads for the "min(mydate)" version. You're a wizard, Harry!
